# check if string found in String in java android studio

Tags: java, android

```
description = "<p>[lang=\"en\"]The large ones[/lang]</p>"

if (description.startsWith("<p>")) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            description = Html.fromHtml(description, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT).toString();
                        } else {
                            description=Html.fromHtml(description).toString();
                        }

                    }
```

//this condition not work string dosn't change

```
if (description.matches("\\[lang=\\\"en\\\"\\]")) {
                        int lenght = description.length();
                        description.substring(7,lenght-7);
                    }
```

i need to remove all html and header `[lang=\"en"\]` from string
and the output is:

> " [lang="en"]The large ones[/lang] "

Comment: please confirm, do you want to get `The large ones` from `"<p>[lang=\"en\"]The large ones[/lang]</p>"`  ?

Comment: yes i need "The large ones" from string

Comment: check my solution, does it give you desired result ?

Comment: if so then please follow [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)

Answer (score 0):

After applying

```
String subString = description.substring(7,lenght-7);
```

Just use replace.

```
subString = subString.replace("[lang=\"en\"]" , "");
subString = subString.replace("[/lang]" , "");
```

Comment: @mahmoudMohamed can you provide the result  and the new code?

Answer (score 0):

I will break the resulting path into two steps -

**Step 1: Removing all HTML tags**

```
String description = "<p>[lang=\"en\"]The large ones[/lang]</p>"
String stringTemp = Html.fromHtml(description).toString();
```

This will give `[lang=\"en\"]The large ones[/lang]` no matter how many HTML tag are present. Eg. result will be same for all these values of description.

```
> <i><b><p>[lang=\"en\"]The large ones[/lang]</p></b></i>
> <HTML><b><p>[lang=\"en\"]The large ones[/lang]</p></b></HTML>
> <HTML><HEAD><b><p>[lang=\"en\"]The large ones[/lang]</p></b></HEAD></HTML>
```

**Step 2: Get StringValue between [lang="en"]StringValue[/lang]**

Once we have our desired String we can manipulate if using many way like using `String.subString()` or use `String.replace()` suggested by @Khaled Alramam.

Using `subString()` as follows -

```
/*
* String.subString(beginIndex, endIndex);
* Note: beginIndex is inclusive but endIndex is the exclusive
* */

String realString = stringTemp.substring(11,(stringTemp.length()-9));
```

Now `realString` will have result as `The large ones` or any string value so far.

Happy coding !